# C-x b completion for shell buffers

Tags: completion

If I

```
M-x shell
C-u M-x shell <RET>
```

I get two buffers, named `*shell*` and `*shell*<2>`.

If I switch to another buffer, and I do

```
C-x b sh <TAB>
```

The echo area doesn't complete to `*shell*` (which is unambiguous at this point), it completes to `shell*`. I then have to

```
C-a * <RET>
```

in order to switch to it. I really dislike this. Is there a way to get the former to complete to `*shell*`, so that I can do

```
C-x b sh <TAB> <RET> <RET>
```

Rather than being forced into

```
C-x b sh <TAB> C-a * <RET>
```

?

What I'm really after is just an easier way to switch to the buffer named `*shell*` than the current way, so suggestions here would also be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend `ido-mode`. It changes how `completing-read` works, adding an inline display of possible matches, and adding several extra keyboard commands for manipulating the list. There are quite a lot of them, but the one I use most frequently is probably `C-s`, which cycles the current list of matches so that the next one is selected.

In your example, `C-x b sh` would match both shell buffers, and hitting enter would select the first one in the list (which would be whichever one you used most recently) and hitting `C-s` would cycle that list to select the next one.

Additionally, if you customize `ido-enable-flex-matching` then it won't require that what you type be an exact substring. You'll be able to type `sh2` and have it match `*shell*<2>`. I use this all the time.

Edit: While I was poking around in the source code, I noticed that you can customize the variable `completion-category-overrides` to change how the default completing works. It's a little complicated, and the help strings aren't readily available in the customization interface as I'd prefer, but you should be able to figure it out. `C-h v completing-styles-alist` will take you to the variable that holds information about the styles, which includes the help strings. It'll be easier to read them if you use the source link to jump to the file they're in, since the indentation will be better and it'll have syntax highlighting. Perhaps one of these styles will suit you better than the default. I still prefer `ido-mode` though.

Comment: Any idea of why it doesn't complete to `*shell*`?

Comment: Which? `completing-read` in vanilla Emacs, or `completing-read` with `ido-mode`?

Comment: The one in vanilla emacs. If it completed to just `*shell*` I wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I haven't examined the commit history for this code, but I suspect that it's simply an oversight. An explanation probably won't fit into a comment...

Comment: In fact, further testing suggests that I don't quite understand the exact behavior; I thought that `try-completion` was doing this, but it isn't. Anyway, you can use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to send a bug report to the mailing list where the Emacs developers will see it.

Comment: When you say "don't understand the exact behavior", do you mean you can't reproduce it, or can't track down the elisp code responsible?

Comment: I can reproduce it, but running `(try-complete "o" '("foo" "foo2"))` doesn't reproduce the problem, so the problem is somewhere in the elisp code that sits on top of that.

Comment: Maybe it is something special to do with the asterisk? I'm on mobile right now and can't test it myself